# Why would I need to change my skin color?

Tags: titan-quest

Titan Quest IT has this potion that I can buy to change my skin color. Why would I need this for? Does it give an advantage in any situation ?

Comment: I haven't played this game but I'd assume it's just cosmetic...?

Comment: I think so too but the potion is expensive. That makes me doubtful :)

Comment: Cosmetics in games have never needed to be *useful* to cost a lot, so the price ain't a good indicator. The most expensive item in the shop in *Mega Man 9* will just change the appearance of Roll's dress, and she's only present in the shop and about 3 cutscenes. I still wouldn't know about Titan Quest specifically, but don't get your hopes up is all I'm saying. ♪

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skins only have a cosmetic effect in Titan Quest.

In any case, are you sure you're using unmodded TQ:IT? because I do not recall any potion that can change the skin, though there are mods such as [AllSkins](http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/threads/22193-Rel-AllSkins-for-TQIT) that work by populating vendors with such potions (that can change a lot more than just the skin tone).

Comment: No I do not have any mods installed.. Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: If you don't know what potion he's talking about, how can you be sure its effects are only cosmetic?